# Spring Security: getting some data from session during logout

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

In my `Spring MVC` web application, I use `Spring Security` for login and logout. In my `spring-security.xml` I have the following:

```
<form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
```

During login, I am setting a TO with user details to session as follows:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("USERTO", userTO);
```

where `userTO` is the object with user details of type `UserTO`. And my logout controller method is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String login(ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error, @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout)
        {
            try
            {
                UserTO user = (UserTO) httpSession.getAttribute("USERTO");
                if (error != null)
                    {
                        //error during login
                    }
                if (logout != null)
                    {
                        //succesful logout
                    }
                model.addAttribute("smartWCMLayoutID", "smartly");
                model.addAttribute("cm", new CommonModel("", "", ""));
                return "smartwcm.login.definition";
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

But during logout, I always get `UserTO` as null. is there any way to capture that vallue from session before logout.

Answer (score 0):

I won't answer directly, but show you another approach. I always attach the following class to my spring-security projects:

```
public class LoggedUserUtils {
    public static User getLoggedUser() {
        final Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        final Object principal = auth.getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof User) {
            return (User) principal;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

It uses `SecurityContext` in which you have `UserDetails` stored. I always implement `UserDetails` interface in `User` class so it works.

You can use the above static method in every controller, service or repository (but I think that only service layer is appropriate, eventually controller as well). In case the call entered via insecure endpoint without the authentication, it'll return a `null`.